# Excel VB - Read Column into 1D Array, Perform Ops, Write Back to Named Range?

Tags: arrays, types, excel, for-loop, vba

I have a data set that contains around 60,000 records. The delinquency date field is right after a field that deals with monetary values and sometimes users enter the monetary value in the delinquency date field by accident. Additionally, they sometimes enter the date as a string ( August, 2st, 2011) or as the number of days delinquent (135 or 135 days). The most common entry method is in the mm/dd/yy format (08/02/11).

Sadly, the programmers of this system refuse to devote the time to create validation for this field, so I must perform as much of it as I can after I have the data. Normally, I would handle this with a few simple formulas, however, there are 19 different ways users enter the data and I need to be able to handle each of them, and quickly. Loading the column into an array seems like the best option.

My thought is to load the column into an array, loop through it, handling all entry options (or deleting the ones that are completely messed up), then write it back to the worksheet. **I know the datatype is the first problem with the array below, but I've only used arrays once before in Excel VB and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. The third line of code is the first problem.** Thanks for your help.

**WORKING CODE PER BRETTDJ'S COMMENTS**

```
'Perform housekeeping on delinquency date
Dim delinquency()
delinquency = Application.Transpose(Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount))
For i = LBound(delinquency) To UBound(delinquency)
    If InStr(delinquency(i), ".") Then
        delinquency(i) = Empty
        Debug.Print "Emptied an array element at row " & i + 1
    End If
    'Additional string or numeric operations here to reformat bad entries.
Next i
Set delRange = Range("AJ1:AJ" & importwsRowCount)
iWS.names.Add Name:="dRange", RefersTo:=delRange
delinquency = Application.Transpose(delinquency) 'Transpose rows and columns
Range("dRange").Value = delinquency 'Write array to worksheet
```

**BAD ENTRY EXAMPLES NEEDING REFORMATTING**
<strike>**SEPT. 25, 20**</strike> (No year, no year! Delete.)
**SEPT** (No year, useless, delete.)
**N/A** (Rubbish! Deleted.)
<strike>**LONG TIME AG**</strike> (What moron thought this was a good idea, delete.)
<strike>**JUNE 30, 200**</strike> (Apparently the field will only hold 12 characters, delete.)
**CHARGED OFF** (Useless, delete.)
<strike>**94 DAYS**</strike> (Take all characters preceding space and subtract from other field containing order date to obtain delinquent date.)
<strike>**94 DPD**</strike> (DPD in someones bright mind stands for Days Past Due I believe. Same as above.)
**2008-7-15 12** (Not sure what additional number is, take all characters before space and transform.)
<strike>**INVALID**</strike> (Delete.)
<strike>**BLANK**</strike> (Do nothing.)
<strike>**12282009**</strike> (Use nested LEFT and RIGHT and CONCATENATE with / in between.)
<strike>**9202011**</strike> (Add leading zero, then same as above.)
<strike>**92410**</strike> (Add leading zero, this will transform to 09/24/10)
<strike>**41261**</strike> (Days since 31/12/1899, this will transform to 12/08/12)
<strike>**1023**</strike> (Days since delinquent, subtract from ORDER DATE to get delinquent date.)
<strike>**452**</strike> (Same as above.)
<strike>**12**</strike> (Same as above.)
<strike>**1432.84**</strike> (Monetary value, mistakenly entered by low IQ lackey. Delete.)

**Updated Code Including Removing Bad Entries (Work in Progress)**

```
'Perform housekeeping on delinquency date
Columns("AH:AH").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    True, Transpose:=False
Dim delinquency()
ReDim del(1 To importwsRowCount, 1 To 1)
del = Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value
For i = LBound(del, 1) To UBound(del, 1)
    delChars = Len(del(i, 1)) 'Determine length of entry
    If IsNumeric(del(i, 1)) = True Then 'Determine datatype of entry
        delType = "Numeric"
    Else
        delType = "String"
    End If
    If InStr(del(i, 1), ".") Then 'Removes monetary entries like 142.84
        del(i, 1) = Empty
    ElseIf InStr(del(i, 1), "*") Then 'Removes ***INVALID*** entries
        del(i, 1) = Empty
    ElseIf delChars = 12 Then 'Removes all entries that extend beyond the 12 character limit of the field and get cut off
        del(i, 1) = Empty
    ElseIf delType = "String" And Len(del(i, 1).Value) < 10 And InStrRev(del(i, 1).Value, " ") Then 'Takes the number from entries like 2194 Days or 23 DPD
        del(i, 1).Value = Left(del(i, 1).Value, Len(del(i, 1).Value) - InStrRev(del(i, 1).Value, " "))
        If IsNumeric(del(i, 1)) = False Then 'If the characters to the left of the space are not numbers, discard
            del(i, 1).Value = Empty
        Else
            del(i, 1).Value = Format((CLng(Range("E" & i + 1).Value) - Abs(del(i, 1).Value)), "mm/dd/yy") 'Pull order date and subtract days from it for delinquency date
        End If
    ElseIf delType = "Numeric" And Len(del(i, 1)) = 5 Then
        If del(i, 1).Value > CLng(Date) Then 'Value is greater than todays date, improperly formated date that needs character manipulation and / added
            del(i, 1).Value = Format(del(i, 1).Value, "000000") 'Add leading zero
            del(i, 1).Value = DateSerial(Right(del(i, 1).Value, 2), Left(del(i, 1).Value, 2), Right(Left(del(i, 1).Value, 2), 4)) 'Grab year, then month, then day for serialize
        Else
            del(i, 1).Value = Format(del(i, 1).Value, "mm/dd/yy") 'Properly formated date that just needs format conversion
        End If
    ElseIf delType = "Numeric" And (delChars = 7 Or delChars = 8) Then
        If delChars = 7 Then
            del(i, 1).Value = Format(del(i, 1).Value, "00000000") 'Add leading zero
        End If
        del(i, 1).Value = DateSerial(Right(del(i, 1).Value, 4), Left(del(i, 1).Value, 2), Right(Left(del(i, 1).Value, 2), 6)) 'Grab year, then month, then day for serialize
    ElseIf delType = "Numeric" And delChars < 5 Then
        del(i, 1).Value = Format((CLng(Range("E" & i + 1).Value) - Abs(del(i, 1).Value)), "mm/dd/yy")
    End If
Next i
Set dRange = Range("AJ1:AJ" & importwsRowCount)
iWS.names.Add Name:="dRange", RefersTo:=delRange
delinquency = Application.Transpose(delinquency) 'Transpose rows and columns
Range("dRange").Value = delinquency 'Write array to worksheet
```

Comment: First thing to do is give your boss a monetary estimate of how much time and money you and your business waste with this data quality issue. Then he can decide if it is worth fixing properly.

Where is the data stored? in a database? You can probably write an UPDATE statement to fix the data permanently.

Comment: ElectricLlama, lol, I wish it was that easy. This is in a CSV file, I am able to download from a portal used to manage accounts in our industry. The portal is used nationally and by quite a few major companies. Essentially, it has wide industry acceptance, and ironically because it does, the programming staff is bare bones. They are pulling in the subscription fees and not providing the support. The system contains highly confidential financial information and there is no way I would ever be given access.

Comment: You might find this article I wrote on [Using Variant Arrays in Excel VBA for Large Scale Data Manipulation](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2684-Using-varinat-arrays-in-VBA-for-large-scale-data.html) useful. For detailed help with your issue you will need to provide more *good data / bad data examples *

Comment: Brettdj, I checked out your article, I'm still not exactly clear how to use a variant array, or what I'm doing wrong in my example above. I am specifically interested in the line with the comment Type mismatch error in relation to the array. I'm reasonably sure I will figure out all the other string manipulation operations.

Comment: Brettdj, that worked! Your example should only have one equal sign though right? Now to figure out how to use some regular expressions in VB to get these entries all straightened out.

Comment: Delete this line `ReDim delinquency(importwsRowCount)` change your transpose line to this `delinquency = Application.Transpose(Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount))`

Comment: *Your example should only have one equal sign though right* Yes - you beat me to a new comment. Using `Regexp` inside the array is also in my article. If you can provide good/bad data then we can help with the full code

Comment: Oh dear, how many times have I seen that - a vendor gets market dominance and screws you because there is no competition.

Comment: Brettdj, I have added the Bad Entry Examples. The Regexp article is behind a paywall for me. Do you have a direct link?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011, v14.1.0, I noticed when reading about Regexp for VB in Excel that you have to enable Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5, will this be a problem since it is not available on the Mac version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the line

```
delinquency = Application.Transpose(["AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount])
```

errors is that `["AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount]` is invalid (it returns a string, not a range).

`[...]` is a shortcut to the `Evaluate` method.  To get it to return a range reference you would need to do something like `[AH1:AH60000]` ie without the `""`.  It would be better to reference the range conventionally

```
delinquency = Application.Transpose(Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount]))
```

That said, you don't actually need to use `Transpose` if you declare `delinquency` as a 2D array.

```
ReDim delinquency(1 To importwsRowCount, 1 To 1)
```

So, your code becomes

```
Dim delinquency() As Variant
ReDim delinquency(1 To importwsRowCount, 1 To 1)
delinquency = Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value
For i = LBound(delinquency, 1) To UBound(delinquency, 1)
    If InStr(delinquency(i, 1), ".") Then
        delinquency(i, 1) = Empty
    End If
    'MANY ADDITIONAL OPERATIONS HERE
Next i
Set delRange = Range("AJ1:AJ" & importwsRowCount)
iWS.Names.Add Name:="dRange", RefersTo:=delRange
Range("dRange").Value = delinquency 'Write array to worksheet
```

Notes:

1. `Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount)` refers to a range on the `ActiveSheet`
2. To be robust you should be explicit in your worksheet references.  So use something like

.

```
Dim wsData as Worksheet
Set wsData = ActiveSheet ' or whatever sheet you want
delinquency = wsData.Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value
Set delRange = wsData.Range("AJ1:AJ" & importwsRowCount) 'assuming you want to refer to the same sheet
iWS.Names.Add Name:="dRange", RefersTo:=delRange  ' not sure what this is for, but be sure your Name referes tot he right sheet
' Might be better to use this, if you need to use the Name at all
iWS.Names("dRange").RefersToRange = delinquency
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you accepted the later post from Chris which partially covered the same ground as my earlier comment I have updated this post as an answer with these changes (the first flagged in my earlier comment)

1. There is no need to `Redim` the variant array prior to using it to capture your range.  It is a redundant line as the variant array automatically fits to the range being fed in.
   <strike>`ReDim delinquency(1 To importwsRowCount, 1 To 1)`</strike>
2. A slight tweak but using `Value2` is better than the default `Value` when working with ranges

You then have a choice between setting up a variant array that is defined as *rows x  columns* or *columns x rows*.

Normally the first approach is taken as the conversion is only necessary when either

1. You are working with a single column or row  and you want to work with a 1D array (as per your question - so yes a `Transpose` is still required)
2. A later `ReDim` will be used to resize array rows. When `Redim Preserve` is used, only the last dimension can by resized. So if you later wanted to reduced the amount of data relating to the *rows* in the array, you need to setup the array with `Transpose` to generate *columns x rows*.

My article on [variant arrays](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2684-Using-varinat-arrays-in-VBA-for-large-scale-data.html) sits outside the EE paywall. Can you please try to view it again?

**standard usage**

```
Sub RowByColumn()
Dim delinquency() 
delinquency = Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value2
```

**Transposed usage**

```
Sub ColumnByRow()
'creates a 1D array when working on a single column or row. creates a *column X row* array on a 2D array
Dim delinquency() 
delinquency = Application.Transpose(Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value2)
```

Comment: Cool! Via microsoft.com: The only difference between Value2 and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

Comment: I did read your article, since I am using OSX 10.8.2 using Excel for Mac 2011, I don't think I have access to that Regex library? It seems like a Windows thing. I currently can write the array back to the worksheet, though as I try to do the data manipulation while looping through the array I receive errors. My other post discusses this better.